# pycairo already installed, but check dependencies says it is not

Tags: python, package, libraries, package-managers, pycairo

Pycairo is already installed, but check dependacies script says it is not installed.

```
Hrishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:graphite hrishikeshparanjape$ brew install py2cairo
Warning: py2cairo-1.10.0 already installed
Hrishikeshs-MacBook-Pro:graphite hrishikeshparanjape$ sudo python check-dependencies.py 
[FATAL] Unable to import the 'cairo' module, do you have pycairo installed for python 2.7.5?
[WARNING]
Unable to import the 'ldap' module, do you have python-ldap installed for python 2.7.5?
Without python-ldap, you will not be able to use LDAP authentication in the graphite webapp.

1 necessary dependencies not met. Graphite will not function until these dependencies are fulfilled.
1 optional dependencies not met. Please consider the warning messages before proceeding.
```

Comment: Maybe related to [Yet another py2cairo installation failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971191/yet-another-py2cairo-installation-failure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mac os x installation of python maintains libraries in a "weird" way. Change your operating system to any distribution of Linux. I installed ubuntu, and it treated me surprisingly well.